# HTML/CSS how to temporarily highlight a section of a page

Tags: html, css

For example, if you go to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060188/how-to-list-all-active-firebase-ci-tokens-or-revoke-them-all/38908695#38908695) it flashes the answer temporarily.

How is this implemented?

Is this some bootstrap/css thing?

I tried googling, but I don't know what this flashing highlight functionality is called.

Comment: try a css transition on page load I guess

Comment: This seems relevant: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions .  I guess I'll answer with a fiddle when I figure it out.

Comment: Here is a fiddle showing basically what I ended up going with: https://jsfiddle.net/a0dhgw8n/

Comment: Why was this closed as a duplicate when the OP doesn't mention jQuery or even JavaScript for that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called the yellow fade technique, there is already a question on SO for this: [Yellow fade effect with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848797/yellow-fade-effect-with-jquery) and here is also some more info on this: https://signalvnoise.com/archives/000558.php
To jump to a section and highlight it you can use :target
More info on this here: https://css-tricks.com/on-target/

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve that using `css animation`, try as below,

```css
div{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  animation:bg 2s ease-in;
  -webkit-animation:bg 2s ease-in;
  -moz-animation:bg 2s ease-in;
  -ms-animation:bg 2s ease-in;
  -o-animation:bg 2s ease-in;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bg{
  0%{
    background:rgba(255,165,0,1);
  }  
  20%{
        background:rgba(255,165,0,0.8);
  }
  50% 70%{
        background:rgba(255,165,0,0.5);
  }
  100%{
    background:rgba(255,165,0,0);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes bg{
  0%{
    background:rgba(255,165,0,1);
  }  
  20%{
        background:rgba(255,165,0,0.8);
  }
  50% 70%{
        background:rgba(255,165,0,0.5);
  }
  100%{
    background:rgba(255,165,0,0);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes bg{
  0%{
    background:rgba(255,165,0,1);
  }  
  20%{
        background:rgba(255,165,0,0.8);
  }
  50% 70%{
        background:rgba(255,165,0,0.5);
  }
  100%{
    background:rgba(255,165,0,0);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes bg{
  0%{
    background:rgba(255,165,0,1);
  }  
  20%{
        background:rgba(255,165,0,0.8);
  }
  50% 70%{
        background:rgba(255,165,0,0.5);
  }
  100%{
    background:rgba(255,165,0,0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>
Dummy Content Dummy ContentDummy ContentDummy ContentDummy ContentDummy ContentDummy ContentDummy ContentDummy ContentDummy ContentDummy ContentDummy ContentDummy ContentDummy ContentDummy ContentDummy ContentDummy ContentDummy ContentDummy ContentDummy ContentDummy ContentDummy ContentDummy ContentDummy ContentDummy ContentDummy ContentDummy ContentDummy ContentDummy ContentDummy ContentDummy Content
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: try adding keyframes rule with -moz- ..I can't see your animation working in my browser :D and just in case the OP have a mozilla browser

Comment: @repzero added and yes in case if OP has mozilla browser. Now it works :-)

Answer (score 3):

This can be implemented with JavaScript.

```js
var bgopacity = 1.0;

var bgfade = function() {
  var comment = document.getElementById("comment");
  bgopacity -= 0.02;
  comment.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255, 242, 130, " + bgopacity + ")";
  if (bgopacity >= 0) {
    setTimeout(bgfade, 30);
  }
}

bgfade();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lpo92shj/

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with css3 animations..

see demo here

```js
var answer=document.createElement('div');
answer.innerHTML='<div id="answer">\
 <h1>\
  My answer\
 </h1>\
</div>'
setTimeout(function(){document.body.appendChild(answer)},3000)
```

```css
@keyframes animate {
  from {
    background: transparent
  }
  50% {
    background: #f2e68e;
  }
  100% {
    background: transparent;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animate {
  from {
    background: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    background: #f2e68e;
  }
  100% {
    background: transparent;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes animate {
  from {
    background: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    background: #f2e68e;
  }
  100% {
    background: transparent;
  }
}

#answer {
  animation-name: animate;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-animation-name: animate;
  -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -o-animation-name: animate;
  -o-animation-duration: 3s;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;  
  -webkit-animation-name: animate;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
Please wait I will inject this answer and hightlight it</div>
```